# Forcing vim to reload already loaded autoload vimfiles

Tags: vim, centos7

I was trying to experiment on auto-load files which vim load at the time of start.
I kept the example.vim file in:

> ~/.vim/autoload/

directory and written a very simple function as:

```
echom "Autoloading..."

function! cpp#running#CompileAndRunFile(commands)
    silent !clear
    execute "!" . a:commands . " " . bufname("%")
endfunction

function! cpp#running#DebuggersOptions()
    " Get the bytecode.
    let bytecode = system(a:command . " -E -o " . bufname("%"))

    " Open a new split and set it up.
    vsplit __Bytecode__
    normal! ggdG
    setlocal filetype=potionbytecode
    setlocal buftype=nofile

    " Insert the bytecode.
    call append(0, split(bytecode, '\v\n'))
endfunction
```

But I want to programatically force a reload of an autoload example.vim file which Vim has already loaded, without bothering the user. The reason being that I want that programmer at run-time can change behavior of the function and load latest modified function.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> auto-load files which vim load at the time of start.

No. The autoload feature is exactly the opposite: an autoloaded script is sourced at runtime, *when a function it contains is called*.

> But I want to programatically force a reload of an autoload example.vim file which Vim has already loaded, without bothering the user.

`:source` it again?

Comment: So Do i need to write autocmd on bufferwrite in .vimrc to source the particular file? Like: `au BufWritePost example.vim :source example.vim`

Comment: That's something to try, yes. You could use `<afile>` in place of the second `example.vim`, though.